# Byte Image data as URL in BotFramework

Tags: c#, botframework

I am building on bot application where i need to show images in Carousel,
I am using Hero card. In this card i need to show image which i am getting from API, image data is in byte format and in herocard it is asking for URI
 cant we pass byte data in Herocard?

```
  allAttachements.Add(new HeroCard
            {
                Title = "test" ,
                Subtitle = "SubTitle",
                Text = "Details",
                Images = new List<CardImage> { new CardImage(url) },
            })
             }.ToAttachment()

            );
```

I tried with  below line but it wont work.

```
string url = $"data:image/png;base64,{ImageData}";
```

Appreciate your help in advance.

Comment: It was my bad i was passing "data:image/png;base64", 2 times thats why image is not showing, now image is visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this:

```
reply.Attachments.Add(new Attachment()
{
     ContentUrl = $"data:image/jpeg;base64,{Convert.ToBase64String(candidate.ImageData)}"
})
```

Comment: Please do not duplicate answers. Look first for duplicates and flag the question instead of adding the same answer.

Comment: Hey @JasonSowers, i have Multiple Herocards and  i am passing multiple cards as attachment hero card

Comment: @EzequielJadib didn't know that existed.  You should be able to repurpose this code, or the code in Ezequiel's  duplicate for your needs.  really all that is missing is the `Convert.ToBase64String(candidate.ImageData)`

Answer (score 0):

It was my bad i was passing "data:image/png;base64", 2 times thats why image is not showing, now image is visible. thanks @JasonSowers @EzequielJadib for your reply